# Implementing a SQLite Database with List<String> as Column type using ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a requirement where I need to store a List in a column in the database. Serializing the list might be an option, but i am not sure if it is the right one.

Also, i want to avoid creating another table to store the list elements and a reference to the original table row.

I am using [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) for the database operations.

Answer (score 0):

Its a concept of foreign collection.

You need to create an entity that wraps the String. Something looks like:

```
 @DatabaseTable
 public class Student {
     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
     print int id;
     @DatabaseField
     private String fname;
     @DatabaseField
     private String lname;
     @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
     private Address address;

 }
Then your Address class would have a ForeignCollection of these Student.

 @DatabaseTable
 public class Address {
     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
     print int id;
     @ForeignCollectionField()
     private ForeignCollection<Student> student;
 }
```

Also refer this [link](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/foreignCollection) , may it will help you.